# Hadoop Mapreduce: Reduce Method not called

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

I'm writing a mapreduce alogirthm.

In my code the `reduce(Text key, Iterable<String> values, Context context)` method is not called. above it I have the `@Override` giving an error : `Method does not override method from its superclass`.

Here is my code:

```
package WordCountP;

import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;


public class popularity extends Configured implements Tool{

    public class PopularityMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        @Override
        protected void map(Text key, Text value,
                           Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

                JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonobject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(new FileReader("src\\testinput.json"));
                    JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonobject.get("votes");

                    Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = jsonArray.iterator();
                    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                        JSONObject obj = iterator.next();
                        String song_id_rave_id = (String) obj.get("song_ID") + "|" + (String) obj.get("rave_ID");
                        String preference = (String) obj.get("preference");
                        System.out.println(song_id_rave_id + "||" + preference);
                        context.write(new Text(song_id_rave_id), new Text(preference));
                    }
                }catch(ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    }

    public class PopularityReducer extends Reducer<Text, Iterable<String>, Text, Text> {

        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<String> values, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {

            int sum = 0;
            for ( String val: values){
                if (val == "true"){
                    sum +=1;
                }
                else if (val == "false"){
                    sum -=1;
                }

            }
            String result = Integer.toString(sum);
            context.write(new Text(key), new Text(result));
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        int exitCode = ToolRunner.run(new popularity(), args);
        System.exit(exitCode);
    }



    public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2) {
            System.err.printf("Usage: %s [generic options] <input> <output>\n",
                    getClass().getSimpleName());
            ToolRunner.printGenericCommandUsage(System.err);
            return -1;
        }

        Job job = new org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job();
        job.setJarByClass(popularity.class);
        job.setJobName("PopularityCounter");

        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
        job.setMapperClass(PopularityMapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(PopularityReducer.class);

        int returnValue = job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0:1;
        System.out.println("job.isSuccessful " + job.isSuccessful());
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

I've tried naming it with R caps, (`Reduce()`) but it didn,t work either.
I assume there is a mistake in the arguments given to the method, but i don't see any problems there... Any ideas?

Secondly, is there any way that I can set the output format te be a `.txt` file?

FYI, my input JSON code is

```
{"votes":[{
    "song_ID": "Piece of your heart",
    "mbr_ID": "001",
    "preference": "true",
    "timestamp": "11:22:33",
    "rave_ID": "rave001",
    },
    {
    "song_ID": "Piece of your heart",
    "mbr_ID": "002",
    "preference": "true",
    "timestamp": "11:22:33",
    "rave_ID": "rave001",
    },
    {
    "song_ID": "Atje voor de sfeer",
    "mbr_ID": "001",
    "preference": "false",
    "timestamp": "11:44:33",
    "rave_ID": "rave001",
    },
    {
    "song_ID": "Atje voor de sfeer",
    "mbr_ID": "002",
    "preference": "false",
    "timestamp": "11:44:33",
    "rave_ID": "rave001",
    },
    {
    "song_ID": "Atje voor de sfeer",
    "mbr_ID": "003",
    "preference": "true",
    "timestamp": "11:44:33",
    "rave_ID": "rave001",
    }]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The code isn't compiling, not that the method isn't called... Once it does run, does the mapper even work correctly? You're not overwriting the default inputformat, so your map types aren't correct

Comment: I changed the reduce method input formats to <Text, String, Text,Text> and the error is gone. Not sure if the code is working properly, i'm going to test now.

Comment: String is not a subclass of Writable, so that shouldn't work either. The default mapper inputs must be `LongWritable, Text`

Comment: I got it! It's indeed a mistake in my mapper inputs

Answer (score 0):

Both IOException and InterruptedException are checked hence the method reduce isn't overridden.

The method reduce in class Reducer does not throw any exception and hence you cannot declare that the method reduce in your subclass throws any checked exceptions but it can throw unchecked exceptions.

You may want to handle the exception inside the reduce method.

Comment: I tried to adjust the location of the Exceptions inside the reduce method, this didn't solve the problem. Why is this an issue? Because the map() method also throws exceptions in the override method;

Comment: @TNelen yeah so you need to make the same changes in the map method as well, as I believe when the objects are being created the parent class reference is used and hence its calling the reduce and map methods inside parent class instead of the methods created by you.

Answer (score 0):

In the end we went for MongoBD mapreduce.

Hadoop is too much of a struggle.

Thanks!